# Extra space in table after adding link

Tags: html, css, html-table, href, whitespace

A while ago I had a problem where an image in a table was not filling the cell, which was covered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621775/spacing-in-a-table/23621843)

However, I now have an edit for this, I need to add links to the image and text. And again, I get the same problem, I've got excess whitespace.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="200px" height="175px"  style="text-align: center; border: 0; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse; "> 
            <a href="http://www.placekitten.com/"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/175" style="display: block; padding: 0; border: 0;" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200px" height="25px"  style="text-align: center; border: 0; background-color: #535152; color: #fffdfe; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse; ">
            <a href="http://www.placekitten.com/">Text</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSRQx/2/)

Is it a case of padding somewhere? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/eSRQx/3/)

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

You should also move your styles out of being inline, into a stylesheet.

[**More on `border-collapse` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

> The border-collapse CSS property selects a table's border model. This
>   has a big influence on the look and style of the table cells.
>
> The separated model is the traditional HTML table border model.
>   Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance
>   between them given by the border-spacing property.
>
> In the collapsed border model, adjacent table cells share borders. In
>   that model, the border-style value of inset behaves like groove, and
>   outset behaves like ridge.

Comment: Thanks - only as I'm using drupal, you can't load any extra style sheets, or add a style section at the start of a page :( so I've added style="border-collapse: collapse;" to the <table> tag

Answer (score 0):

You should move or add `border-collapse:collapse` to your table instead of your td.

`border-collapse` is a `table` property not `td`'s.

and more info: [border-collapse](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/)